# How to define function types when they will be monadic, IO and pure

Tags: haskell

(Related question [Select instance behavior at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034826/select-instance-behavior-at-runtime))

I want to define a kind of backend (reusable as independent api), then provide multiple implementations and be able to select one at runtime.

My application will be like

```
data AppData =
     AppData { ...
             , backend :: Backend
             }
```

for simplicity, let our backend (**conceptual code**)

```
data Backend key value =
     Backend { get :: [(key, value)]
             , cud :: key -> Maybe value -> () -- Create Update Delete
             }
```

now **What's the proper/recommended way to define our `Backend` type?**

I think it will be monadic (then `Monad m`) but also `IO` (then `MonadIO m`) but also pure (then we need change `-> ()` by `-> Backend key value`) and so on...

I'm doubting, the next attempt works monadic, `IO` and pure, but may be over-engineering

```
data Backend m k v =
     Backend { get :: MonadIO m => m [(k, v)]
             , cud :: MonadIO m => k -> Maybe v -> Backend m k v
             }
```

the `MonadIO` is a strong restriction and return immutable version on `cud` is redundant (in most cases?) with `m`.

**What is the proper/recommended way to abstract it?**

Thank you!

Once defined our `Backend` API my intention was use as (**conceptual code**) more or less

```
main = do
    configuration <- getAppConfiguration
    selectedBackend <- case preferedBackend configuration of
                           "mongoDB"  -> MongoDBBackend.makeBackend
                           "sqlite"   -> SqliteBackend.makeBackend
                           "volatile" -> PureDataMapBackend.makeBackend
                           ...
    appData <- makeAppData configuration selectedBackend
    ....
```

Comment: Um... could you give some examples of how you'd like to use this?

Comment: My goal is minimize backend restrictions and maximize abstraction. Updated! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7438716/477476

Comment: I'm sorry @Cactus but I cannot see how it solve my doubt.

Comment: @josejuan that answer might give you a good idea of why your definition of `Backend` is going down the wrong path.

Comment: Mm... I'm still not sure but `k` and `v` restrictions blow up at `selectBackend <- ` and for each `makeBackend` as needed. I've used `GADTs` also but "record" was recommended to me (sorry if I don't understand you)

Comment: What are the types of the operations in question for the backends you want to support?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need a non-`IO` backend as well, then I'd suggest to parametrize the data type by the monad in which its operations run. As pointed out by @Cactus, there is no need to add constraints to the data type itself. It doesn't help anything, it just makes things complicated. Instead, these constraints will be at functions that create various `Backend`s.

Also, while it might be possible to vary the return type of the update function, using such a function would be just hell, as the application would basically need to cover all (both) cases whenever using the function. So instead I'd suggest to keep the result simple, just monadic. And for the pure backend you can just run the application within the `State` monad, for example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.State

data Backend m key value = Backend
    { beGet :: m [(key, value)]
    , beCud :: key -> Maybe value -> m () -- Create Update Delete
    }

pureBackend :: (MonadState [(k, v)] m, Eq k) => Backend m k v
pureBackend = Backend get pureCud
  where
    filterOut k = filter ((/= k) . fst)
    pureCud k Nothing = modify (filterOut k)
    pureCud k (Just v) = modify (((k, v) :) . filterOut k)

-- other backends ...
```

This means that `AppData` and whoever else uses `Backend` needs to be parametrized by the monad as well.